# How To Get Value Of Input Tag In Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How To Get Value Of Input tag in typescript.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="demo111" (click)="chk(this)" name="schoolFactors" value="Yes" >Yes
```

I'm using the below code but not sure how to get & set the input box value using typescript in angular.

```
chk(this){
   console.log(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use two way data binding. You can do this.

In HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
   <input name="player" value="Name">
</form>
```

In component

```
onSubmit(event: any) {
   return event.target.player.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the circumstances, another way that does not have to involve a `<form>` is by using `ViewChild` and `elementRef`. A very simplistic example:

**HTML:**

```
<input #cb type="checkbox" id="demo111" (change)="chk(cb.value)" name="schoolFactors" value="Yes" >Yes
```

**Class code:**

Demonstrates getting (via parameter from the HTML and directly in code) and setting the value:

```
  @ViewChild('cb') cb: ElementRef;

  chk(e): void {
    const nativeCb = this.cb.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;

    console.log(e, nativeCb.value);
    nativeCb.value = 'no';
  }
```